# how to get cityname from address php, googlemaps

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

i need to find the cityname from the address, i have to take input(single textbox with streetname, cityname,country) for ex: skyline Blvd 35, California, USA.

$str = "skyline Blvd 35, munchen, Germany";

result: munchen

What i thought was to first find the lat and lng and then do reverse geo to get the cityname.
lat n long: developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#geocoding

reverse geo:developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#ReverseGeocoding

I am wonderring if there is another way of getting the cityname may be from the string itself..

skyline BLVD35, munchen, germany.

Comment: California is not city name

Comment: it was just an example.... Grrr

Comment: it is very bad misleading example, as addresses in US and UK have different format and it is not a trivial task to parse them properly and extract city

Comment: okay, so to get to the point how do i get the cityname from the input string otherthan doing geocoding and reverse geocoding...

Comment: short answer which suits SO format: it is almost impossible, long answer - read about all possible address formats, prepare database with existing city/county/state/country names and depending on user IP/language preferences/selected country _try_ to parse string into something meaningful. Just note - google does not always do correct job, so good luck

Comment: Even using google reverse geocoding, you'll get a hierarchy of administrative subdivisions. In certain countries the second or third administrative subdivision might mean city, while in others it could mean municipality, county, region, neighborhood, etc. Using the input string to guess the city name beforehand could only work if you could enforce a given format. Otherwise, you're pretty much screwed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = file_get_contents( "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=" . urlencode( "skyline Blvd 35, California, USA" ));
$o = json_decode( $x );
foreach ( $o->results[0]->address_components as $component ) {
    if ( $component->types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_1' )
        print $component->long_name;

}
```